# Consume WFS Stored Query with Parameters using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, wfs

I am working on providing data from our application in a WFS friendly format. I have set up a stored query with parameters that is to be used to return a feature collection. My stored query is within our own web application, not through ArcGIS. A simple call to my stored query with just one parameter looks like:

```
http://localhost/AWQMS/api/wfs?service=wfs&request=GetFeature&storedQuery_id=GetFeaturesByParameters&OrganizationIdentifiersCsv=BISHOP_PAIUTE_TRIBE_WQX
```

I want to be able to consume this using ArcMap. So far in ArcMap I can set up an Interoperability connection with my url http://localhost/awqms/api/wfs and my capabilities seems to work alright...at least my Feature Types list populates correctly in the Constraints section of the connection's parameters window.

I only have a single FeatureType and was planning to rely upon the stored query's parameters to narrow down which features are actually returned.

1. Is this a reasonable approach or should I be thinking differently about this?
2. How can I consume my stored query with parameters using ArcMap?